# Where are the EXEs for Subsystem For Unix Applications so I can use it?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, sua

I am on Windows 7 Ultimate.

I have done done start..ctrl panel..programs..turn windows features on and off...and ticked Subsystem For Unix Applications

[image]

When I click the start menu, I see it isn't installed but it has 
[image]

I then followed the link in my start menu which went to a webpage to download it. No need to register and it downloaded Utilities and SDK for UNIX-based Applications_X86.exe

```
 extracted it to C:\sua32

    C:\sua32>dir
     Volume in drive C has no label.
     Volume Serial Number is DC46-3C68

     Directory of C:\sua32

    11/18/2014  11:25 AM    <DIR>          .
    11/18/2014  11:25 AM    <DIR>          ..
    11/18/2014  11:24 AM    <DIR>          BaseUtils
    11/18/2014  11:24 AM    <DIR>          docs
    04/01/2008  01:21 PM           170,557 install.htm
    11/18/2014  11:24 AM    <DIR>          manage
    11/18/2014  11:24 AM    <DIR>          SDK
    11/18/2014  11:25 AM    <DIR>          setup
    04/02/2008  02:57 AM            24,120 setup.exe
    04/02/2008  02:57 AM         1,638,912 setup.msi
    11/18/2014  11:25 AM    <DIR>          sources
    04/02/2008  02:57 AM            24,120 upgrade.exe
                   4 File(s)      1,857,709 bytes
                   8 Dir(s)  126,447,235,072 bytes free

    C:\sua32>
```

I notice it has a setup.exe (which I will run), and it has files that look like they would be the commands but they have no exe extension.

```
C:\sua32\BaseUtils\bin>dir
....
01/18/2008  06:18 AM           101,888 wc
01/18/2008  06:19 AM           118,784 who
01/18/2008  06:19 AM               591 whoami
...
             212 File(s)     36,907,662 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  126,443,298,816 bytes free

C:\sua32\BaseUtils\bin>
```

I ran setup.exe

and it installed to C:\windows\sua

```
C:\Windows\SUA>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is DC46-3C68

 Directory of C:\Windows\SUA

11/18/2014  12:05 PM    <DIR>          .
11/18/2014  12:05 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/18/2014  12:06 PM    <DIR>          bin
11/18/2014  12:04 PM    <DIR>          common
11/17/2014  05:52 PM    <DIR>          dev
11/18/2014  12:04 PM    <DIR>          docs
11/18/2014  12:06 PM    <DIR>          etc
11/18/2014  12:04 PM    <DIR>          help
11/16/2014  11:11 PM    <DIR>          net
11/18/2014  12:05 PM    <DIR>          opt
11/16/2014  11:11 PM    <DIR>          proc
11/18/2014  12:05 PM    <DIR>          svr-5
11/16/2014  11:11 PM    <DIR>          tmp
11/18/2014  12:05 PM    <DIR>          usr
11/18/2014  12:04 PM    <DIR>          var
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
              15 Dir(s)  126,443,307,008 bytes free

C:\Windows\SUA>
```

It includes these files in `C:\Windows\SUA\bin>`

```
01/18/2008  06:18 AM           101,888 wc
01/18/2008  06:19 AM           118,784 who
01/18/2008  06:19 AM               591 whoami
```

I see no exe extension, and no special shell

How are these meant to run?  Or, how am I meant to run these?

I can rename or copy a command e.g. who to who.exe and run it but surely that's not how i'm meant to run it.

How am I meant to run these?

Comment: Have you tried simply running `C:\Windows\SUA\bin\whoami`? A file does not need to be named `.exe` to be executable.

Comment: @slhck   Just tried it, it didn't run. It said `'c:\windows\sua\bin\whoami' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`  (out of interest, what, if any, setting do you have that can make extensionless files run as executable?)

Comment: No idea; I'm a Unix person :) But I'd also guess you need to add the bin directory to your PATH. And maybe then these executables just work.

Comment: @slhck no.  you don't need to add the directory to the path if (as you suggested earlier) you give the absolute path(or if you are in the directory and do `.\command`. i'm largely a windows guy but I know many *nix commands. I already took into account re the path. I just tried adding it to the path, no difference.

Comment: Do you have Bash or KSH on the start menu somewhere?  That works for me.

Comment: @dsolimano I might make a new question out of that.. i'll let you know..

Comment: @slhck brief note, worth noting that windows has a whoami command.

Comment: @dsolimano I can't get commands running in ksh  i.e. in the shell that appears after running ksh.bat  http://superuser.com/questions/841795/in-windows-suasystem-for-unix-applications-i-cannot-get-ksh-to-run-commands

Comment: @dsolimano by the way, how did you notice that ksh was in the start menu? I see it when I search for ksh though it doesn't appear in any folder

Comment: @barlop SUA installs "Subsystem for windows" in the start menu  including "Korn Shell" and "C Shell".  If you were to run ksh.bat then do as as the shortcut does, so with `-l` ksh -l i.e.  ksh.bat -l otherwise you get errors. This is covered here http://superuser.com/questions/841795/in-windows-suasystem-for-unix-applications-i-cannot-get-ksh-to-run-commands/841837#841837

Comment: @barlop, I suppose I just knew what to look for from having run SUA on prior windows versions.

Answer (score 4):

While there are only two EXE files in c:\windows\sua\bin   (just cat32.exe and fileinfo.exe) and a load of commands that would run but are missing an EXE extension!)

C:\Windows\SUA\bin>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is B411-D580

```
 Directory of C:\Windows\SUA\bin

17/11/2014  11:09 AM    <DIR>          .
17/11/2014  11:09 AM    <DIR>          ..
18/01/2008  06:09 AM           172,032 at
18/01/2008  06:09 AM           172,032 atq
18/01/2008  06:09 AM           172,032 atrm
18/01/2008  01:45 AM           396,288 awk
18/01/2008  05:41 AM           115,200 banner
18/01/2008  01:45 AM           105,472 basename
18/01/2008  06:09 AM           172,032 batch
18/01/2008  07:01 AM           141,824 bp
18/01/2008  06:05 AM            46,605 c89
18/01/2008  06:05 AM           117,760 cal
18/01/2008  06:05 AM           140,800 calendar
18/01/2008  01:45 AM           118,784 cat
18/01/2008  01:45 AM           155,648 cat32
18/01/2008  01:45 AM           155,648 cat32.exe
.....
```

There are EXE files for not all but most of the commands, in `c:\windows\sua\common`

```
C:\Windows\SUA\common>dir *.exe
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is DC46-3C68

 Directory of C:\Windows\SUA\common

01/18/2008  04:42 AM            97,280 basename.exe
01/18/2008  05:05 AM           135,168 cat.exe
01/18/2008  05:05 AM           134,144 chgrp.exe
....
01/18/2008  06:19 AM           121,856 wc.exe
              29 File(s)      4,773,376 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  126,438,662,144 bytes free


C:\Windows\SUA\common>
```

There are some e.g. awk which don't have an exe file but are in c:\windows\sua\bin   and you don't have to rename them to run them, they run from an SUA shell e.g. start..programs..subsystem for unix..c shell  then ls /bin and awk shows there.

Also, I hadn't noticed initially but installing SUA does add  `C:\windows\sua\common\` and `c:\windows\sua\usr\lib\"` (with a trailing backslash oddly enough),  to the path.

Related followup question now answered - [In Windows SUA(System for Unix Applications), I cannot get KSH to run commands. Even ls fails](https://superuser.com/questions/841795/in-windows-suasystem-for-unix-applications-i-cannot-get-ksh-to-run-commands)