# In Windows SUA(System for Unix Applications), I cannot get KSH to run commands. Even ls fails

Tags: windows-7, command-line, sua

I have managed to install Windows SUA(Subsystem for Unix Applications), in Windows 7 Ultimate. I can run the commands in `c:\windows\sua\common` straight from cmd.exe but I want to try running commands from the korn shell. I see ksh in the start menu if I type in ksh into the search box. But I get an error when I try to run commands from there.

I see if I click start and type ksh, then I see ksh.bat  which is in c:\windows\SUA\common\ksh.bat

When I run ksh.bat and then do `echo $PATH`

I see directories including `/dev/fs/C/Windows/SUA/common:/dev/fs/C/Windows/SUA/usr/lib`

And for the record I have `ls.exe` here

```
C:\Windows\SUA\common>dir ls.exe<ENTER>
01/18/2008  05:40 AM           174,592 ls.exe
```

But when I run ksh.bat
then I try to run `ls`, it says

```
$ ls
/bin/ksh: ls: not found
$ cd
$
$
```

Comment: This question still relevant since you figured out what was going in the other one?

Comment: @Ramhound yes it's very relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see now in the start menu there is an entry "Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications" but oddly it didn't come up with orange highlight (which new entries normally do), so I didn't notice it. Here it is expanded.

[image]

Choosing  Korn Shell from there, opens it up. It runs the line `C:\Windows\posix.exe /u /c /bin/ksh -l`

And then ls works

Whereas running ksh.bat alone, doesn't work.

The difference between that command line, and ksh.bat

Is ksh.bat does `posix /u /c /bin/ksh %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9`  which if you run ksh.bat with no parameters, it equates to  `posix /u /c /bin/ksh`  i.e. no `-l` (i.e. no dash el)

Whereas the korn shortcut, does the same line but with -l.

If you run ksh -l  then that would be running ksh.bat with -l and as c:\windows\posix.exe is covered in the path, looking at the command line used by ksh.bat, it is(when with -l) then the same as what the shortcut does, and thus works just as the shortcut works.

So, either run from the shortcut, or run the bat file with ksh -l

Prior related question [Where are the EXEs for Subsystem For Unix Applications so I can use it?](https://superuser.com/questions/841733/where-are-the-exes-for-subsystem-for-unix-applications-so-i-can-use-it/841786#841786)